# ParaView record partially?

Tags: android, vtk, google-project-tango, paraview

A few days ago I installed ParaView TangoRecorder (https://github.com/Kitware/ParaViewTangoRecorder) and I'm in trouble.

I tried to use it to record a little table but the result was that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUNhd.jpg

All the files are in VTK file format.

In a few words: I record a table but when I use the ParaView PC software I noticed that the record was incomplete. I walked around the table in every single position but it's incomplete.

Can I modify the app to solve that?

Thanks

Comment: I also notice that the poses.vtk file shows what I'm talking about. I tried to put the poses file over the normal vtk file and it's more evident the fact that a part of the recording is missing.